# NullPointerException with Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE with Vaadin 8.3

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, vaadin8

I am using Spring Boot version 2.0.0 with Vaadin 8.3. Everything in my eclipse is working fine, but when I created WAR file and deployed into my tomcat 8.5.29 Server, the Vaadin UI throws NullPointerException. Everything else except Vaadin Components is working fine. Please help me!

The detailed exception is given below:

> Type: Exception Report
>
> Message: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Description: The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:447)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:166)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   Root Cause
>
> com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1653)
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1613)
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:166)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   Root Cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.getAllChildrenIterable(AbstractClientConnector.java:516)
>     com.vaadin.ui.ConnectorTracker.markConnectorsDirtyRecursively(ConnectorTracker.java:617)
>     com.vaadin.ui.ConnectorTracker.markConnectorsDirtyRecursively(ConnectorTracker.java:618)
>     com.vaadin.ui.ConnectorTracker.markConnectorsDirtyRecursively(ConnectorTracker.java:618)
>     com.vaadin.ui.ConnectorTracker.markAllConnectorsDirty(ConnectorTracker.java:592)
>     com.vaadin.server.LegacyCommunicationManager.repaintAll(LegacyCommunicationManager.java:439)
>     com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:78)
>     com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:166)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

Comment: Please share a SSCCE. My first guess is that there's something wrong with widgetset. Are you using the Vaadin 7 compatibilty layer?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich I am not using any widgetset. I am using Vaadin 8 libraries. BTW I have solved this problem by using SpringVaadinServlet. Previously I was using VaadinServlet.

Comment: Ok, please add your solution as answer for future reference.